# Pass driver ChromeOptions and DesiredCapabilities?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

The new Google chrome update causes this message in the browser "You are using an unsupported command-line flag: --ignore-certificate-errors. Stability and security will suffer."

From what I read on selenium bug reports, the temporary solution is to start webdriver with

```
options.AddArgument("test-type")
```

I was already passing DesiredCapabilities when creating the driver. How can I pass both ChromeOptions and DesiredCapabilities to the driver?

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
capabilities.setCapability("chrome.switches", Arrays.asList("--incognito"));

ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("test-type");

WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I was fighting the same problem, and I finally cracked it. Basically, you can add `ChromeOptions` to `DesiredCapabilities` then create the driver with the `DesiredCapabilities`. Once I tried it, it got rid of the banner. Anyway, here is the code:

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("test-type");
capabilities.setCapability("chrome.binary", "<Path to binary>");
capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
webDriver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
```

Comment: This is deprecated in WebDriver 3.6.0.

Comment: Yes. Passing capabilities to ChromeDriver constructor is Deprecated.

Answer (score 9):

**Adding my answer to help users who are still looking for ChromeOptions and Capabilities with Selenium latest version.**

Passing capabilities to ChromeDriver constructor is Deprecated from v3.6.0. [Source code Reference](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/chrome/ChromeDriver.html)

```
ChromeDriver(Capabilities capabilities)
Deprecated. 
Use ChromeDriver(ChromeOptions) instead.
```

Instead you should start using something like below :

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setAcceptInsecureCerts(true);
options.setUnhandledPromptBehaviour(UnexpectedAlertBehaviour.ACCEPT);
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options)
```

You can still have your capabilities defined, but make sure you merge these capabilities with ChromeOptions like below:

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setCapability("something", true);

ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("disable-infobars");
options.merge(capabilities);
```

You can check article on [Selenium ChromeOptions](http://www.seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/using-chrome-options-for-webdriver-tests) for more detailed usage on ChromeOptions and Capabilities

Answer (score 2):

FYI: This technique does not appear to work with Chrome 41.0.2272.101m.

```
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.AddExcludedArgument("ignore-certificate-errors");
capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.Chrome();
capabilities.SetCapability(ChromeOptions.Capability, chromeOptions);

new RemoteWebDriver(hubUri, capabilities, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(180))
```

Generates

```
09:39:24.110 WARN - Exception: unknown error: cannot parse capability: chromeOptions
from unknown error: unrecognized chrome option: Arguments
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.10.267521,platform=Windows NT 6.3 x86_64) 
(WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 1.52 seconds
Build info: version: '2.43.0', revision: '597b76b', time: '2014-09-09 20:52:14'
System info: host: 'T10-E8-GREGPE', ip: '10.123.160.70', os.name: 'Windows 8.1', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_40'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
```

This appears to work:

```
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.AddArgument("test-type");
capabilities = (DesiredCapabilities)chromeOptions.ToCapabilities();

new RemoteWebDriver(hubUri, capabilities, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(180));
```

Comment: `capabilities = (DesiredCapabilities)chromeOptions.ToCapabilities();` was the magic hidden api I was looking for to work with a remote webdriver. Why does nobody use webdriver remote these days? I am doing this in python, but the api call `to_capabilities()` is not surfaced anyplace else.

Answer (score 0):

may be try this:

```
chromeOptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {"profile.managed_default_content_settings.images":2}
chromeOptions.add_experimental_option("prefs",prefs)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chromeOptions)
```

related info can found here:
http://nullege.com/codes/search/selenium.webdriver.ChromeOptions.add_experimental_option

Answer (score 0):

```
public void setUp() throws Exception
{
    System.out.println("Launching Google browser");
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\chromedriver.exe");   

    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addArguments("disable-infobars");
    Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    prefs.put("profile.default_content_setting_values.automatic_downloads", 1);
    options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
    prefs.put("download.default_directory", "C:\\Downloads");
    driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.manage().window().maximize(); 
}
```