# Unsupported command-line flag: --ignore-certificate-errors (in Ruby)

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Using Ruby 2.0.0 p481 in RubyMine and chromedriver 2.10

When Chrome starts it displays a message in a yellow popup bar: "You are using an unsupported command-line flag: --ignore-certificate-errors. Stability and security will suffer." This simple example reproduces the problem.

```
require "selenium-webdriver" 
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome 
driver.navigate.to login_url
```

This question has been answered for Java and Python.  I have looked everywhere for a Ruby analog.  Does anyone have a suggestion or know how to translate the Python answer ([Unsupported command-line flag: --ignore-certificate-errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24168407/unsupported-command-line-flag-ignore-certificate-errors)) to Ruby?  Thank you!

Comment: Thank you to both Nguyen Vu Hoang and mtm.  Between the two, I just added a :switch with --test-type argument and that took care of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Ruby selenium-webdriver API](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/rb/index.html) doesn't expose a separate Chrome options object like Java/Python but you can set the options via ["Capabilities"](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/capabilities).

The [Capabilities web page](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/capabilities) provides a Ruby example and the [table of recognized capabilities](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/capabilities#TOC-List-of-recognized-capabilities) that you can inject. Plugging those together with `excludeSwitches`:

```
caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome("chromeOptions" => {"excludeSwitches" => [ "--ignore-certificate-errors" ]})
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome, desired_capabilities: caps
```

Take a look at [Watir](http://watirwebdriver.com/) too, it's a front end for WebDriver.
Their [examples](http://watirwebdriver.com/chrome/) show how you can send a [`:switches` array](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/rb/lib/selenium/webdriver/chrome/bridge.rb#57) which is passed straight through to the web driver so you can do the same. That makes adding other switches a bit easier rather than going through capabilities.

There is a [chromedriver](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/rb/lib/selenium/webdriver/chrome/bridge.rb#57) issue on the topic as well.  There are posts detailing that you can add a `--test-type` argument to work around the certificate issue and [ruby code examples](http://watirwebdriver.com/chrome/) like above.

Answer (score 1):

I adjusted:

```
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome
```

to read:

```
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome, :switches => %w[--test-type]
```

...and the script ran successfully without the yellow flag.  Clearly, other command-line switches could be added.

Thank you to Nguyen Vu Hoang and mtm.

Answer (score 0):

I donot know ruby, however my approach is set mode "test-type" to ChromeDriver capabilities

Here's my sample code in Java

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("test-type", "start-maximized",
        "no-default-browser-check");    
capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
```

Answer (score 0):

### With `Capybara`:

```
Capybara.register_driver :chrome do |app|
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :chrome, switches: ['--test-type'])
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This error caused my rspec tests to fail. I think it was causing Chrome to slow down so the above fixes did remove the error messages but did not resolve my problem of my tests failing.

If you are using [chromedriver-helper](https://github.com/flavorjones/chromedriver-helper) then this should fix the problem. Run this from the command line

```
chromedriver-update
```

This is described more in [chromedriver-helper](https://github.com/flavorjones/chromedriver-helper), "This might be necessary on platforms on which Chrome auto-updates, which has been known to introduce incompatibilities with older versions of chromedrive"

Once I ran this I was able to remove the fixes described elsewhere and Chrome ran with out warnings.