# Python Selenium: Unable to Open Chrome Browser

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium

Whenever I try it says Chrome closed unexpectedly and asks to reOpen. At python end it gives error:

```
  raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: was killed
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.0,platform=Mac OS X 10.10.2 x86_64)
```

My code is:

```
driver = None
profile = webdriver.Chrome('/Setups/chromedriver')
driver.set_window_size(1128, 768) # optional
url = 'http://google.com'
driver.get(url)
```

**Update**: running in verbose mode gives this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to set size of `none` object. Try

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Setups/chromedriver')
driver.set_window_size(1128, 768)
```

Comment: Same error despite of that silliness from my side: `riverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: was killed`

Comment: If you don't use the latest chrome driver version download it and try again.

Comment: *Google Chrome 47.0.2526.111 (Official Build) (64-bit)*

It's the updated one?

Comment: Not Google Chrome, ChromeDriver. Download from [here](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads), Last version 2.20

Comment: [This](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=590) may also be useful.

Comment: I am on OSX 64 so I think that would be the issue? I already downloaded the latest one?

Comment: adding `--verbose` did the trick but it is not navigating to URL and gives notification that I am opening Chrome without certificates.

Comment: This message shouldn't cause problems (I have seen it before)

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24169131/5168011) also might do the trick @Volatil3