# Selenium Chrome Error: You are using an unsupported command-line flag: --ignore-certifcate-errors

Tags: java, selenium, web-scraping, google-chrome-devtools, selenium-chromedriver

Okay so I am learning Web Scraping and am comfortable with Java hence I choose Jsoup, which is a web scraping library. I planned on scraping [A CodeChef contest problem](https://www.codechef.com/problems/FRGTNLNG) (which is just a coding problem),  but I found difficulty scraping all the displayed content, which is not possible as most of it is dynamic source. So I used selenium to render the JavaScript and obtain simple HTML page and then feed it to JSOUP.

So I tried printing the rendered HTML page just to verify, but I get the following error when I run the code:

My Code:

```
    File f = new File("<Path to chromedriver.exe>");
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", f.getAbsolutePath());
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("https://www.codechef.com/problems/FRGTNLNG");
    System.out.println(driver.getPageSource());
```

Error (in chrome):

```
You are using an unsupported command-line flag: --ignore-certifcate-errors. Stability and security will suffer
```

I tried the following solution from [Chrome Error: You are using an unsupported command-line flag: --ignore-certifcate-errors. Stability and security will suffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32042187/chrome-error-you-are-using-an-unsupported-command-line-flag-ignore-certifcat), I installed the latest chromedriver but it didn't resolve my error.

I also tried adding Desired Capabilities (now deprecated) and ChromeOptions as per [Pass driver ChromeOptions and DesiredCapabilities?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23834413/pass-driver-chromeoptions-and-desiredcapabilities?noredirect=1&lq=1), but the same error persists.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

The error says it all :

```
You are using an unsupported command-line flag: --ignore-certifcate-errors. Stability and security will suffer
```

As per best programming practices, use the `ChromeOptions` Class to open *Chrome Browser* being *maximized*, *disabling the infobars* and *disabling the extensions* as follows :

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\path\\to\\chromedriver.exe");
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("start-maximized");
options.addArguments("disable-infobars");
options.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
options.addArguments("--test-type");
options.addArguments("--ignore-certificate-errors");
WebDriver driver =  new ChromeDriver(options);
driver.get("https://www.google.co.in");
```

Additionally, perform the following steps :

- Update your JDK to the most recent versions [*JDK 8u162*](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html)
- Upgrade *Selenium-Java Clients* to [**v3.10.0**](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).
- Upgrade *ChromeDriver* to the latest release [*ChromeDriver v2.35*](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/)
- Clean up the *Project Space* from your IDE.
- Run [***CCleaner***](https://www.ccleaner.com/ccleaner) tool to wipe off all the OS system chores.
- If your base *Web Browser* version is too old, then uninstall it through [***Revo Uninstaller***](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) and install a recent GA and released version of the *Web Browser*.
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- Execute your *@Test*

Comment: I tried all of above but the error still shows. Is there any specific argument for ignoring certificates?

Comment: I've tried everything (except updating my browser), seems like a browser version issue to me. Anyways, I moved to HTMLUnit which worked perfectly fine for me!

Comment: only `--test-type` is needed, see also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36746675/10440128)