# How to run selenium in multiple docker containers while changing proxy?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, docker, selenium-webdriver

Thank you all in advance for all your patience and kindness. I am new to docker and have trouble utilizing it to achieve my task. Please kindly let me know if I posted anything incorrectly instead of down voting.

I am working on a crawler project and trying to use docker + selenium + multiple proxies. Here is my ideal work flow: There is one machine containing multiple containers, one spider(selenium) script runs in one container, and each script will finish "fetch and render website -> extract information -> update local database" process.

I know how to change proxy in selenium in local. Here is part of my script:

```
def get_driver():
    driver = getattr(threadLocal, 'driver', None)
    if driver is None:
        chromeOptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        chromeOptions.add_argument("--headless")
        chromeOptions.add_argument('--proxy-server=http://pubproxy.com/api/proxy？format=txt')
        prefs = {
            "profile.managed_default_content_settings.images": 2,
            'disk-cache-size': 4096,
            'permissions.default.stylesheet': 2
        }
        chromeOptions.add_experimental_option('prefs', prefs)
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chromeOptions)
        setattr(threadLocal, "driver", driver)
    return driver
```

I am able to finish "fetch and render website -> extract information -> update local database" process with proxy in local but I am not sure whether I can deploy it on multiple docker containers.

I checked this post: [How to configure special proxy settings for a remote selenium webdrive with python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51198774/how-to-configure-special-proxy-settings-for-a-remote-selenium-webdrive-with-pyth). But I am still confused that whether I should change the proxy in docker setting because I saw such an example:

```
from selenium import webdriver 
chrome = webdriver.Remote( command_executor='http://localhost:4444/wd/hub', desired_capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.CHROME )
```

If I change the IP in docker setting, does it mean I need to stop and open it repeatedly?(That is not ideal for a spider?)

Am I able to pass configuration parameters to the docker chrome selenium webdriver or do I need to build the docker container with the proxy settings preconfigured before building it?

Any hint on achieving/optimizing this work flow would be appreciated. I am following the official docker tutorial and got lost. Sincerely hope someone can help me on the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass proxy to function e.g.  **get_driver(proxy)**

Yo can make a simple function choosing from list of given proxies in file that shares a [volume](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volume-configuration-reference) with your container, which you will be able to edit any time.

```
def get_driver_with_random_proxy():
    with open('proxy_file.txt') as file:
        proxies_list = file.read().split('\n')
        random_proxy = random.choice(proxies_list)
    return get_driver(random_proxy)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This is helpful. And I have some more questions. Seems I can open multiple containers on different ports and they can get the proxies from one sharing file/database. Is it correct? Or should I just used 4444? I am still confused about this part.

Comment: @Serena you can use any ports you like.
And you probably want second filled with used proxies to make sure each container uses its own proxy.